# SendGrid sent to spam on internal domain

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid with a whitelabel to send email from my domain name, `a-non-existent-account@example.com`. The whitelabel works perfectly for outside delivery, but when sending to an inside account on O365 `internal.user@example.com` the messages are trapped in the O365 spam filter.

The headers are showing a passing dkim for my traffic, which I should be able to build a transport rule on but I have no idea how to do it.

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 208.117.55.133)
smtp.mailfrom=whitelabel.example.com; example.com; dkim=pass
(signature was verified) header.d=example.org;example.org;
dmarc=temperror action=none header.from=example.org;compauth=pass
reason=111
```

I'm thinking I need a transport rule based off the whitelist Authentication-Results header, but I'm at a loss as how to do it. I don't want to have to pay for a static IP from SendGrid unless absolutely necessary.

This is really a tiny issue in the grand scheme, but really annoying at the same time.

Comment: SPF and DKIM both passed, so why is DMARC showing a temperror?

Comment: You should open a case with Microsoft on this. They’ll tell you how to fix the problem within a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the domain into ‘Allow domain’ under spam filter in Exchange Online ECP.